# Count results inside foreach then store that value in a variable to be used elsewhere

Tags: php, foreach

How do you count the results inside a foreach then store that value in a variable to be used on another foreach.

Example. This foreach returns 5 items

```
foreach ($xml->items as $item) {
  echo "$item->name";
  echo "$item->address"; 
}
```

Now I want that the foreach above be counted and stored in say $totalitems and be used on another foreach. This second foreach also counts its results and store in $totalitems2. Something like this:

```
foreach ($xml->items as $item) { //Same source but they will be displayed separately based on a condition.
  echo "$item->name";
  echo "$item->address";
  if_blah_blah_meet_condition_then_break;
}
```

So basically what I want here is to restrict the total number of items being displayed on both foreach combined. $totalitems and $totalitems2 should have the sum of 8. 8 is the number I want limit the items returned. Doesn't matter if the other foreach has more items than the other. 3 and 5. 4 and 4. 6 and 2. Etc.

How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: +1. Since its not 0% he -does- know how to accept questions

Comment: I'm a noob here guys. I don't know what that means.

Comment: To the left of an answer, there is a checkbox outline. If the particular answer answers your question, check inside the outline, and it will turn green. Keep in mind that you can only select one, so choose the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the simple iterator `++` methods. When you are on the second `foreach`, watch for when `$i` **passes** the number that you want to stop it.

#### Code:

```
$i = 0;    
foreach ($xml->items as $item) {
    echo "$item->name";
    echo "$item->address";
    $i++;
}

foreach ($xml->items as $item) {
    echo "$item->name";
    echo "$item->address";

    $i++;
    if ($i > 5) { // or whatever the number is
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$totalItems = count($xml->items);
foreach ($xml->items as $item) {
  echo "$item->name";
  echo "$item->address"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count($xml->items)` and that value in the condition, inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your array is stored in `xml->items` therefor, you only would have to save it in another variable if you want to store it.

```
foreach ($xml->items as $cont=>$item) {
  echo "$item->name";
  echo "$item->address"; 

  if($cont<8){
      $totalItems_one[] = $item; 
  }
}

//whatever changes you do to $xml->items

foreach ($xml->items as $cont=>$item) {
  echo "$item->name";
  echo "$item->address"; 

  if($cont<8){
      $totalItems_two[] = $item; 
  }
}
```

Like this you have the two new arrays `totalItems_one` and `totalItems_two` and you can get the number of items just doing `count($totalItems_one)` or `count($totalItems_two)` whenever you want.